# Слово "так" в текстах разговорной речи

Tags: разговорная-речь

Какой часть речи является слово "так" в предложении:

Так (?) и дальше что?

И следует ли обособлять его запятой?

Answer (score 3):

**В зависимости от контекста и интонации** могут быть разные решения.

См. примеры с необособлением слова «так».

Алексей Чернов «Демон внутри каждого»:

> [Корнилов]: – <…> Задурили девке голову. Она и «поплыла». Написала
> явку с повинной. Мол – это все я. Сожитель мой ни в чем не виноват. Я
> продавала, и так далее.
>
> – Во баба дает! – не выдержал Шлыков.
>
> Корнилов пожал плечами: – Женщины, особенно когда влюблены, вообще
> способны на многое.
>
> – **Так и дальше что?**

Александр Канторович «Башни над городом»:

> – Ну, может, ты и прав… – через некоторое время возвращается на свое
> место седоусый. – **Так и дальше-то что?** Кто это таков?

В этих примерах «так и» – **частица**, близкая по семантике к «ну и». Предложения произносятся на едином дыхании, никаких знаков препинания внутри них не требуется.

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите значение частицы ТАК И по толковому словарю, а также стилистку такого употребления частицы (нейтр., разг., простор.).  "Ну и дальше что?" – нейтр. стиль.

Comment: @Слава, спасибо! А есть примеры с обособлением этого слова?

Answer (score 2):

***Так**, и дальше что?*

Сравним: ***Это так** (= верно), и дальше что?*

По смыслу «так» – это **подтверждение** того, что сказанное собеседником принято к сведению и что с этим говорящий согласен.

Часть речи – местоименное **наречие**; в разговорной речи оно получает как бы функцию **вводного слова,** то есть становится авторской **пометкой** «согласен».

Большой толковый **словарь** Кузнецова:

***ТАК***. I. местоим. нареч. 1. Именно таким образом, не как-нибудь иначе. **Это так (верно).**